# Unable to debug UWP app in Visual Studio 2015 on a device from VMWare Fusion

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10, vmware

I am implementing a Xamarin app for UWP (and Android and iOS). I'm using VS2015 in VMWare Fusion VM on a Macbook Pro. I am able to build and debug the UWP app in an Emulator without any problems. However I am not able to deploy and debug to a connected Lumia 950 phone over USB. The deployment starts and fails after a while with the message: DEP0001: Unexpected Error -2147023436.

It looks to me as if the file transfer over the USB is not working - however the device is connected and I can communicate with it from the virtual machine.

I have tried a lot, such as using the WinAppDeployCmd.exe command line tool to deploy to the phone. It recognizes the device and starts the package upload and then hangs.

Anybody had the same problem?

Comment: What app (if any) did you launch when the phone connected? I've seen debugging fail if you don't choose the "Phone Companion" app in the past...

Comment: I only launched Windows explorer, and it works. I can browse the phone file system in Explorer and copy small files to and from the phone - which indicates that the USB connection is working. However if it seems to hang I try to copy large files from the phone to the machine, which is suspicious.

Comment: Normally when you plug in a Windows Phone, it will prompt to launch an app (e.g. Phone Companion; Photos, OneDrive). If [Phone Companion isn't started, I've seen issues debugging in the past](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/11914/106) - might be worth starting that app manually

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - but I did install the phone companion and launched but have the same problem.

Comment: Hi @arividar, did you find any solution? I have the same problem and i really tried everything i could... I don't know how to go on...

Comment: Sorry to say @marco.marinangeli - we did not find a solution to this. I have a Lenovo Windows machine (i.e. nonvirtual) which I use for development as well. There is no problem deploying the app to the device from it.

Comment: @arividar ok thanks! now i know that maybe i will build someday... I'm preparing a windows machine... i hope i'll be lucky as you ;)

Comment: @arividar just to let other people know. My problem was the same: on a physical machine it all went good.